# How I can I prevent JS error "Expected 'function' at column..."?

Tags: function, error-handling, bootstrap-datepicker

This is my datepicker:

```
   $('#daterange-btn').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
            'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
            'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
        endDate: moment(),
        function (start, end) {
            $('#daterange-btn span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        };
    });
```

I get the error message:

> Expected 'function' at column 9, not column 12  function (start,end){
>   Expected an identifier and instead saw 'function' (a reserved word):
>   Expected ':' and instead saw '('. Missing space between '(' and
>   'start'. 'start' was used before it was defined. Expected 'end' at
>   column 9, not column 29.